# make UILocalNotifications display badge only

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have been looking at the API for UILocalNotification. I want to set just the badge number when the firedate is hit. no pop-up. I tried setting my notifications to just having a badge number of 1 and no alert body. but this didnt work.

```
//Add new local push notification
locationNotification.fireDate = date;
locationNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
//locationNotification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:body];
//locationNotification.alertAction = @"Ok";
//locationNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
locationNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
```

Is this possible? I only want to display the message once they have opened the app.

Answer (score 1):

I accomplished something like this for a project I worked on. I needed to only display a badge number, with no alert. You may need to add a 'sound' to the notification, what I did was add a `0.5` second silent sound file. My code looks like this.

```
        UILocalNotification *notif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        notif.fireDate = [NSDate  date];
        notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        notif.soundName = @"silence.caf";
        notif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 2;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];
        [notif release];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for the reply skram, looks like the only thing im missing in my code is the sound name. i tried  leaving it as the UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName but this didnt seem to make a difference

Comment: Also, double check that your expected time of `fireDate` is valid. Otherwise you can be expecting something thats not really happening.

Comment: if i uncomment the alertbody and action if works ok. so i think the fireDate is ok.

Comment: I keep reading i can set the badge to midnight of the fireDate. As far as your aware should the localNotification only work for the date? Im testing it against time at the moment.

Comment: That's probably your problem. Set the fireDate `5 minutes` ahead of your current time. Background or Close the app, and wait for it to Fire and see if it changes your Badge.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but hopefully this will help someone. I didn't think it was possible to schedule silent Local Notifications at all, but it seems that it is.

This works:

```
    UILocalNotification* notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    notification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10];
    notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
    notification.alertBody = nil;        
    notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 99;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
```

I also tried adding some information to the userInfo property so that I could identify this notification in the scheduled notifications, however this seemed to prevent the notification from being fired.

Instead of that, I'm now using a silent audio file as the soundName property so that I can test for that. The silent audio file does not however seem to be necessary to actually get the notification to fire.

If you want to do anything more useful than updating the badge to a value that you know at the time of scheduling, then you need to use silent push notifications and set the "content-available" flag.